# Why are responses from nomatim different when accessing page with browser or with requests?

Tags: python, json, python-requests, openstreetmap, nominatim

I'm fetching JSON data from this URL

http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/?q=san%20francisco&format=json&addressdetails=1&limit=1

This is output when viewed on the web browser

```
[{"display_name":"San Francisco City and County, California, United States of America","class":"boundary","type":"administrative","importance":0.88836369596997,"icon":"http:\/\/nominatim.openstreetmap.org\/images\/mapicons\/poi_boundary_administrative.p.20.png","address":{"county":"San Francisco City and County","state":"California","country":"United States of America","country_code":"us"}}]
```

When I fetch the same URL from a simple python program

```
import requests

r = requests.get('http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/?q=san%20francisco&format=json&addressdetails=1&limit=1')
json_data = r.json()

print json_data
```

This is what I get,

```
[{u'display_name': u'SF, California, United States of America', u'importance': 0.68836369596997, u'place_id': u'127766562', u'lon': u'-122.4629897', u'lat': u'37.7647993', u'osm_type': u'relation', u'licence': u'Data \xa9 OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright', u'osm_id': u'396487', u'boundingbox': [u'37.63983', u'37.9298443', u'-123.1738249', u'-122.2817799'], u'type': u'administrative', u'class': u'boundary', u'address': {u'county': u'SF', u'country': u'United States of America', u'state': u'California', u'country_code': u'us'}, u'icon': u'http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/images/mapicons/poi_boundary_administrative.p.20.png'}]
```

Notice the display_name starts with `SF,California, Unite.....`

I've tried deleting all history/cookies/cache and even restarting the computer

What is going on?

Comment: You'd have to ask Nominatim that. It is their server that alters behaviour, after all.

Comment: I don't see any problem here. If you're worrying about the "u" before each string, this is because the server returns unicode strings.

Comment: @richerlariviere No, I'm worrying about the word 'SF' prepended to the display_name value

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with Python (wget gives the same result), and everything with Nominatim varying their responses based on what kind of client they think they're talking to.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich: more what language preferences the client communicated.

Answer (score 7):

The server looks for an `Accept-Language` header; don't send one and you get the abbreviation, send one stating you accept English and you get the full name:

```
>>> import requests
>>> url = 'http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/'
>>> params = {'q': 'san francisco', 'format': 'json', 'addressdetails': 1, 'limit': 1}
>>> requests.get(url, params=params).json()[0]['display_name']
u'SF, California, United States of America'
>>> requests.get(url, params=params, headers={'Accept-Language': 'en'}).json()[0]['display_name']
u'San Francisco City and County, California, United States of America'
```

The [Nomatim documentation](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim) does mention that the header is used, but can be overridden by specifying a `accept-language` parameter in the query string:

```
>>> print requests.get(url, params=dict(params, **{'accept-language': 'pt'})).json()[0]['display_name']
SF, Califórnia, Estados Unidos da América
```